# find substring in a string, but look from the right to the left excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-formula, substring

I had originally asked the question below and found a good formula 
[excel formula find part number in file path text string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792735/excel-formula-find-part-number-in-file-path-text-string)

So after using the `=MID(A1,SEARCH("????-??????-??",A1),14)` formula to find the part number names things seemed fine until I ran into data that looks like the sample set below.

```
c:\users\stuff\folder_name\folder_name_9876-vv-123-Ag\1234-000001-01_ baskets_1.pdf
c:\users\stuff\folder_name_9876-vv-123-Ag\random file_1234-000001-02_ baskets_2.pdf
c:\users\stuff\folder_name_XXXX-XXXXXX-XX\1234-000001-03_ baskets_3.pdf
c:\users\stuff\folder_name\1234-000030-01_ tree_30.pdf
c:\users\stuff\folder_name\random text_1234-000030-02_ tree_30.pdf
c:\users\stuff\folder_name\more random stuff_1234-000030-02_ tree_30.pdf
```

I am looking thru a few hundred thousand file names and I know I am missing some important files due to the false positive triggers. Like  `9876-vv-123-Ag` it technically fits the `????-??????-??` format but is not what I want to extract from the string. Now to the question, is there a way to apply `=MID(A1,SEARCH("????-??????-??",A1),14)` that can look from the right side of the string and work its way left to ensure that it grabs the last sub-string in the full string that meets the  `????-??????-??` format?

or is there a way to set the wildcard search to numeric only instead of anything in that `????-??????-??` format?

Comment: This seems like a good fit for regex (VBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other ambiguities, you can search just the file name portion of the file path, and return the matching string:

```
=MID(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99)),SEARCH("????-??????-??",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99))),14)
```

[image]

If there are other ambiguities, you will need to be more specific

This portion of the formula:  `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",99)),99))`
returns the last substring where the string is split on the "\" character.  If it might be the case that the file name might have more than **99** characters, then increase the **99** appropriately, or use something like `LEN(A1)` instead.

If you want to use a VBA routine, the following routine processed 500,000 rows in less than 4 seconds.  It does depend on the part number consisting of only digits, but the change would be trivial if other patterns need to be included.

```
Option Explicit
Sub partNum()
Dim RE As Object
Dim R As Range, WS As Worksheet
Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
Dim I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(vSrc, 1), 2))
End With

ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To 1)

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{2}"

    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
        If .test(vSrc(I, 1)) = True Then vRes(I, 1) = .Execute(vSrc(I, 1))(0)
    Next I
End With

R.EntireColumn.Clear
R = vRes

End Sub
```

**VBA Function** *(stand-alone)*

```
Option Explicit
Function getPartNum(S As String) As String
Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{2}(?!.*\\)"
    If .test(S) = True Then getPartNum = .Execute(S)(0)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: tried the formula version and still got a few false positives. `z:\folder7\test\Firmware\app-1.9_boot-1_4090-990123-01.sap` somehow gave me  `boot-1_4090-99` as a result even though the part # is `4090-990123-01`. Not a huge issues since you formula has a better hit rate then the one I was originally using.

Comment: @AlbertoBrown It might be possible to modify the formula to account for that; much simpler to just use the VBA macro (or an equivalent VBA function if that is simpler for you).

Comment: yeah I was about to start messing with that vba code. my only question was `With WS
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(UBound(vSrc, 1), 2))` in that line the `.Cells(1,1)` & `.Cells(1,2)` refers to A1 and B1 correct? I need to adjust the address to my sheet. And what change would be needed to accept a letter in the middle 6 or last 2 digits?

Comment: `.Cells(1,1) & .Cells(1,2) refers to A1 and B1 correct?` Yes.  And to change the regex to accept a letter **or** a digit, change `\d` to `[A-Za-z0-9]`  `\d` is a shorthand character for `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

## Obvious Solutions

### Excel Substitution Version (6s for 50000 rows)

Works only for 2 possible occurrences of the string choosing the last.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2));"";IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2;SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2)+1));MID($A2;SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2);LEN("????-??????-??"));MID($A2;SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2;SEARCH("????-??????-??";A2)+1);LEN("????-??????-??"))))
```

---

### A Sub Version (96s for 50000 rows)

```
Sub SearchQ2()

  Const cStrSource As String = "A2"
  Const cStrTarget As String = "B2"
  Const cStrSearch As String = "????-??????-??"

  Dim vntRange As Variant
  Dim lngSearch As Long
  Dim intStart As Integer
  Dim lng1 As Long
  Dim strTemp As String

  vntRange = Range(cStrSource).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, Range("A1").Column) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - Range(cStrSource).Row + 1)

  For lng1 = 1 To UBound(vntRange)
    intStart = 1
    Do
      On Error Resume Next
      lngSearch = WorksheetFunction.Search(cStrSearch, _
          vntRange(lng1, 1), intStart)
      If Err Then
        Exit Do
       Else
        strTemp = Mid(vntRange(lng1, 1), lngSearch, Len(cStrSearch))
        intStart = lngSearch + Len(cStrSearch) + 1
      End If
    Loop
    vntRange(lng1, 1) = strTemp
  Next

  Range(cStrTarget).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, Range("A1").Column) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - Range(cStrSource).Row + 1) = vntRange

End Sub
```

---

### The Worst Function Ever

It works fine for a hundred, maybe a few hundred cells. This might be an inspiration for someone to write an efficient function.

It loops through the string to find the last occurrence of the SearchString.

```
Function SearchQ(SearchString As String, Cell As Range) As String
  Application.Volatile
  Dim lngSearch As Long
  Dim intStart As Integer
  intStart = 1
  Do
    On Error Resume Next
    lngSearch = WorksheetFunction.Search(SearchString, _
        Cell.Cells(1, 1).Text, intStart)
    If Err Then
      Exit Do
     Else
      SearchQ = Mid(Cell.Cells(1, 1).Text, lngSearch, Len(SearchString))
      intStart = lngSearch + Len(SearchString) + 1
    End If
  Loop
End Function
```